# How to generate a value using pre defined mask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitmask

I am working on a hardware that is a bit tricky...for example one its 32bit registers looks like this (the upper 16bits are all zero)

```
#define MASK_DBG_CTRL_FIFO_SPLIT            0b0000000000000001
#define MASK_DBG_CTRL_FIFO_ENABLE           0b0000000000000010
#define MASK_DBG_CTRL_ADC_SPLIT             0b0000000000000100
#define MASK_DBG_CTRL_ADC_ENABLE            0b0000000000001000
#define MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_COUNTER           0b1111111111110000

#define NO_SPLIT                            0  
#define WITH_SPLIT                          1
#define DISABLE                             0  
#define ENABLE                              1
```

My question is, how can I generate a number that I need to write into this register. E.g. I will have a function that gets numbers from user and returns the value ready to be written to register.

This seems to be a very painfull process...I have a dozen of similar registers that have different bit-width and stuff...How can I make this easier?

For one, How do I even write a desired value at the `MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_COUNTER` bits?

```
uint32_t generateDebugRegister(uint8_t fifoSplit, uint8_t fifoEnable,
                                uint8_t adcSplit, uint8_t adcEnable,
                                uint16_t counter) {
    uint32_t output = 0;

    switch(fifoSplit) {
    case NO_SPLIT:
        //do nothing;
        break;
    case WITH_SPLIT:
        output = 1UL >> 1; //set bit 0 to 1
        break;
    }

    switch(fifoEnable) {
    case DISABLE:
        //do nothing;
        break;
    case ENABLE:
        output = 1UL >> 2; //set bit 2 to 1
        break;
    }

    switch(adcSplit) {
    case NO_SPLIT:
        //do nothing;
        break;
    case WITH_SPLIT:
        output = 1UL >> 3; //set bit 3 to 1
        break;
    }

    switch(adcEnable) {
    case DISABLE:
        //do nothing;
        break;
    case ENABLE:
        output = 1UL >> 4; //set bit 4 to 1
        break;
    }

    //how to evenset the counter value???

    return output;
}
```

Example of calling function:

```
void setDebugRegister(uint32_t value) { /*write to reg*/ };

uint32_t toWrite = generateDebugRegister(NO_SPLIT, DISABLE, WITH_SPLIT, ENABLE, 4256);

setDebugRegister( toWrite);
```

Here is another set of register masks...here I neeed to set the low 10 bits spliced into two 5 bits:

```
#define MASK_DAD_NUM_ADDR                   0b0000000000011111
#define MASK_DAD_NUM_DECI                   0b0000001111100000
```

Here, top 8 bits and low 8 bits:

```
#define MASK_DBG_REG_ID                     0b1111111100000000;
#define MASK_DBG_REG_CNTR                   0b0000000011111111;
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you give examples of inputs and outputs expected?

Comment: The result of `output = 1UL >> 2;` is like `output = 0;`.  What was really wanted? `<<`?

Comment: To set a bit: `output |= (uint32_t)1 << bit_position;`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I updated my question with example usage

Comment: @chux nothing in my code example works correctly :) I just tried but it all fails...

Comment: Hint: `output &= ~FEATURE_MASK; output |= FEATURE_VALUE << FEATURE_SHIFT;`

Comment: @EugeneSh. `output &= ~FEATURE_MASK;` is a good idea yet one must be careful when `output` is wider than `unsigned/int`, as `~FEATURE_MASK` may clear bits more-significant bits than `unsigned`.  An alternative: `output |= FEATURE_MASK; output ^= FEATURE_MASK;` to avoid wdith issues.

Comment: @chux XORing with mask won't work. It will set the corresponding bit if it is unset.

Comment: @EugeneSh. XORing after ORing will always clear the bit.  Let the compiler then optimize into the equivalent `and`.

Comment: @chux Oh, I see what you are saying.

Comment: I think your example shows the incorrect shift. For example, to set bit 1 to 1: `output = 1UL << 1;`, likewise, to set bit 0 to 1: `output = 1UL << 0;`. However, as *chux* has pointed out in his response, you want to use the bitwise 'or': `output |= (1UL << 1);`. This is made clearer, using your defines, by: `output |= MASK_DBG_CTRL_FIFO_ENABLE;` But, as written, each time a switch block is entered, and is "true", the result is simply assigned discarding what was present. Using the right-shift with 1, always assigns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to generate a value using pre defined mask (?)

To address OP's first part:

Consider a re-write of the function signature.  Other suggested changes below as comment code.

```
// uint32_t generateDebugRegister(uint8_t fifoSplit, uint8_t fifoEnable,
//     uint8_t adcSplit, uint8_t adcEnable, uint16_t counter) { ...

// use bool for simple T/F values
uint32_t generateDebugRegister(bool fifoSplit, bool fifoEnable, bool adcSplit, 
    bool adcEnable, uint16_t counter) {

  uint32_t output = 0;
  if (fifoSplit == WITH_SPLIT) {   // use an `if()`
    output |= MASK_DBG_CTRL_FIFO_SPLIT; // use an 'or' of the mask
  } 
  if (fifoEnable == ENABLE) {
    output |= MASK_DBG_CTRL_FIFO_ENABLE;
  }
  .... // like-wise with  adcSplit, adcEnable

  // add an `offset` to simplify shifting needs
  #define MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_BIT_OFFSET 4
  #define MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_MAX (MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_COUNTER >> MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_BIT_OFFSET)

  // test, since 16 bits do not fit in 12
  if (counter > MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_MAX) {
    Handle_error_with_TBD_Code();
  }
  else { 
    output |= (uint32_t)counter << MASK_DBG_CTRL_MAX_BIT_OFFSET;
  }

  return out;
}
```

> I have a dozen of similar registers that have different bit-width and stuff...How can I make this easier?

Need to see some of those for a good general answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added two more of the registers at the end of my question.

Comment: Chux, thanks for your answer it solved my problem, would you kindly also give a hint as to how to set `MASK_DAD_NUM_ADDR` and `MASK_DAD_NUM_DECI` that I updated in my question?